# Saving results from RETURNING in separate variables

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Problem

Say I have the following insert statement:

```
insert into table_1 (...) values (...), (...), (...);
```

Assuming I know those 3 rows will be correctly inserted (no clause is violated), how can I fetch the `id` field of each inserted row into a separate variabile in order for me to use it in the rest of the `.sql` script?

---

#### What I tried

I've read about `returning` which would presumably translate into:

```
insert into table_1 (...) values (...), (...), (...) returning id;
```

I've also read about `with` (Common Table Expressions) which could "save" the result of `returning` into a table for later use in the following `insert` statements;

but it appears that I would then have to get the `id`s as `select id from temp_table` associating some kind of selector to distinguish between each 3 rows.

---

#### Question

Is there a way to get the `id`s of each inserted row to later use them, separately, in a different `insert` statement?

Comment: Maybe if you `array_agg` that returning ID and assign it to array variable, then sorting order will be the same as inserts and you will be able to just do my_arr[1], my_arr[2] to get ID of specific rows.

Comment: Aggregate functions are not allowed in returning.

Comment: You are correct, but you can make your insert inside CTE and do `SELECT array_agg(returned_id) INTO my_ids FROM ins_cte`. From what little test I did it seems to preserve order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use three CTEs:

```
with i1 as (
      insert into table_1 (...) values (...)returning id
     ),
     i2 as (
      insert into table_1 (...) values (...) returning id
     ),
     i3 as (
      insert into table_1 (...) values (...) returning id
     )
insert . . .;
```

This doesn't put the values into three variables.  It does put them in three separate CTEs so each can be referred to individually.

Comment: And I have to reference the `id` as `select id from i1 limit 1`?

Comment: @Shoe . . . That would be one approach.